# Sourdough more rise in the oven

Tags: sourdough

It is a while sinse I baked any sourdough. After 6 days of feeding the starter and 2 12 hour proofs the rise in the loaf was not fantastic but about doubled when I baked it. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Yippy for you. The term for the expansion of the loaf in the oven is " oven spring " and it is a good thing. Artisan bread bakers cut the top or sides of the loaf so it does not tear when it springs. There is tool called a [lame'](http://breadtopia.com/store/bread-lame/) for this purpose. It is a razor blade mounted on a stick or wand so that it is curved. To use you need to perfect the technique of scoring the loaf with a flick of the wrist. Sounds like you have nice healthy sourdough.

Comment: I used a loaf tin, not a proper bread tin and it stuck. Looked terrible, tasted great. Bought myself A proper bread tin. Next Loaf is tomorrow morning Melbourne Australia time, which is aprox 16 hours from now. Is every 2nd day okay to feed starter?

Comment: @Locky - If you keep the starter at room temperature, you need to feed it every twelve hours.  If it is kept in the fridge, you can feed it every week without problems. http://blog.kingarthurflour.com/2012/04/08/maintaining-your-sourdough-starter-food-water-and-time/